# numpy array error:operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (0,) (10,)

Tags: python, numpy

Please notice the code and error (at the last part) what I put as below

```py
for t in range(0, timePeriod): 

    #---------------------------------------------------------------    
    for i in range(n):  
        #-------------------------------------------------------

        ...
        ...

        old_capital =  Capital_m[:-t]   #Averaged captial at t -1

        current_capital = Capital[:]

        Capital_m[:] = memory * old_capital + (1-memory) * current_capital
```

output when print variables:

```py
old is: []
current is: [1.09556224 1.01866678 1.         1.09329266 1.05955302 1.
 1.         1.         1.         1.        ]
    
    177     Capital_m[:] = memory * old_capital + (1-memory) * current_capital
    178     
    179 

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (0,) (10,)
```

Comment: Your `current_capital` is a vector which has 10 values, while `old_capital` is a scalar. What is the expected result ?

Comment: @AcaNg, `np.array([])` isn't a scalar.  It's a 1d array with 0 elements, shape (0,)

Comment: @hpaulj my bad, sorry. It should be "an empty array" instead.

Comment: This is not just a "review my code" board, but a Q&A. Please rewrite it to point out your questions, indicating what possible answers you already considered. See also help/intro pages!

Comment: Thank you for your response above. Please let me say what I' like to do with the code. I want to endow agents in my model with simple memory. And I thought this can be done very easily just by adding a variable for each agent that describes the capital it remembers: initialize by (memorized capital) = (the current capital) and update by (new memorized capital) = m*(old memorized capital) + (1-m)*(the current capital), where m < 1 describes the strength of memory.

Comment: In the code "old_capital = Capital_m[:-t]" means # agents' capital at the previous time period(t) sequence, "current_capital = Capital[:]" means # agents's current capital which calculated already, and "Capital_m[:] = memory * old_capital + (1-memory) * current_capital' means # new updated memorized capital. As a matter of fact, when I replace the "old_capital" with just "Capital[:]", it works, but when I put the code like "old_captial" it shows an error. The error was from a mismatched NumPy array due to the "old_capital = Capital_m[:-t]" but I could not find a solution by myself.

Comment: It would be best to edit this information into the question, rather than post it in the comments. Please edit the question and make it stand alone with a clear indication of what help you need.

Answer (score 0):

You showed that `old_capital` is `[]`:

```
In [36]: np.array([])+np.array([1,2,3])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-36-22a078a68ad7>", line 1, in <module>
    np.array([])+np.array([1,2,3])
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (0,) (3,)
```

The must be because the `t` value in:

```
old_capital =  Capital_m[:-t]
```

is too large.  The slice is empty.

```
In [38]: np.arange(3)[:-3]
Out[38]: array([], dtype=int64)
In [39]: np.arange(3)[:-2]
Out[39]: array([0])
```

Comment: Thank you for your response above. Please let me say what I' like to do with the code. I want to endow agents in my model with simple memory. And I thought this can be done very easily just by adding a variable for each agent that describes the capital it remembers: initialize by (memorized capital) = (the current capital) and update by (new memorized capital) = m*(old memorized capital) + (1-m)*(the current capital), where m < 1 describes the strength of memory.

Comment: In the code "old_capital =  Capital_m[:-t]" means # agents' capital at the previous time period(t) sequence, "current_capital = Capital[:]" means # agents's current capital which calculated already, and "Capital_m[:] = memory * old_capital + (1-memory) * current_capital' means # new updated memorized capital. As a matter of fact, when I replace the "old_capital" with just "Capital[:]", it works, but when I put the code like "old_captial" it shows an error. The error was from a mismatched NumPy array due to the "old_capital =  Capital_m[:-t]" but I could not find a solution by myself.